# Innodb crashes, mysql doesn't start until server reboot

Tags: mysql, apache, amazon-ec2, innodb

i have the following Issue.

I have an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance with LAMP installed on it.

My WebApp uses InnoDB tables. If there are a lot of users, InnoDB used to crash because of buffer pool size. It says it cannot allocate enought memory.

> 170511 10:32:05 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12

I have put **innodb_buffer_pool_size** to 750M (if I put it more that 1GB - mysql doesn't start at all). And I have put stress test of my WebApp under LoadImpact. From 30 person and up WebApp  was trying to allocate something like 800M and crashes MySQL again.

> 170511 12:16:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 752.0M
>
> InnoDB: mmap(807010304 bytes) failed; errno 12

Another problem is that I cannot just run **sudo service mysql start** or **restart** after mysql Crash. It says job failed to start.

1. How to make my server more stable. What options should I use.
2. How to prevent such "crashy" behaviour. I mean can I make something that makes server and mysql prosess not chash but freeze or something like that. I dont want do **sudo reboo** every time there are a lot of people on the website

Comment: MySQL is **not** crashing. It is being killed by Apache then denied the resources that it needs, in order to restart.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25083/11651

Answer (score 0):

t2.micro instance has only 512M RAM. If you run MySQL and Apache on same box you should allocate memory sparingly.

It looks like apache processes use up all memory so MySQL gets less than necessary minimum.

I would suggest to start with adding swap if you haven't added it yet.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=65536
chmod 0600 /swapfile
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```

and add it to `/etc/fstab`.

```
/swapfile          swap            swap    defaults        0 0
```

Next, limit Apache workers to make sure MySQL always gets `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Depending on what you use - prefork or worker configuration will be different, but you got an idea.